# How can I get Location name from JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to get Location name from a JSON data. I did it with:

```
 var adsress = JSON.stringify(dataa.Response.ResourceSets.ResourceSet.Resources.Location.Address.AddressLine["#text"]);
```

but when I changed the location point I can't do the same since it shows:

> Cannot get ['#text'] of null or undefined var

The result( JSON data ):

```
 "Resources":{"Location":[{"Name":{"#text":"Rue Ibnou Battouta, Agadir, Morocco"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hJVjf/

Comment: *"but when i changed the location point"* What does that mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: That is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.Response.ResourceSets.ResourceSet.Resources.Location` is an array.

Try

```
 data.Response.ResourceSets.ResourceSet.Resources.Location[0].Address.AddressLine["#text"]
```